# NSString starting with # using componentsSeparatedByString does not work

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

My code is as follows:

```
NSArray *modifyVersionOnDevice  [FileHandler parseFile:devicepath];
NSString *param = [modifyVersionOnDevice objectAtIndex:1];

//param at this point is one element with string of "#MAJREV: 3"

//As soon as I run the next line, I get an error Unrecognized selector sent 
to instance.

NSArray *d =[param componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

If I hard code

```
NSString *param =@"#MAJREV: 3";  it works
```

Comment: Presumably `[modifyVersionOnDevice objectAtIndex:1];` is _not_ an `NSString`. What do you get if you log `[param class]`?

Comment: "Unrecognized selector sent to instance." is a well known error, but it also gives helpful information that you didn't provide. What's the full error message on console?

Answer (score -4):

Turns out you have to convert param into a literal string.

```
NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[modifyVersionOnDevice objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Then
    NSArray *d =[param componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

Comment: That isn't doing what you think it is doing.   You aren't creating a literal string and the object at index 1 is clearly not a string.